# Inform JSON object with dataframe pandas

Tags: python, json

I have some information in a dataframe and I want to convert it into a json file.

Right now I have this:

```py
def function(token, url_variable):

    res = requests.get('url' + str(url_variable), headers = 
                                                  {'Content-Type' : 'application/json', 
                                                   'authorization': token})
    text = res.text
    data = json.loads(text) 

    json_data = {
        'id': data['id'],
        'openingTimes': {'1': [{'opening': '12:00', 'closing': '16:00'},
        {'opening': '19:00', 'closing': '22:00'}],
        '2': [{'opening': '12:00', 'closing': '15:00'},
        {'opening': '19:00', 'closing': '22:00'}],
        '3': [{'opening': '12:00', 'closing': '15:00'},
        {'opening': '19:00', 'closing': '22:00'}],
        '4': [{'opening': '12:00', 'closing': '15:00'},
        {'opening': '19:00', 'closing': '23:00'}],
        '5': [{'opening': '12:00', 'closing': '15:00'},
        {'opening': '19:00', 'closing': '23:00'}],
        '6': [{'opening': '12:00', 'closing': '15:00'},
        {'opening': '19:00', 'closing': '00:00'}],
        '7': [{'opening': '12:00', 'closing': '16:00'},
        {'opening': '19:00', 'closing': '00:00'}]},
        'phoneNumber': data['phoneNumber'],
        'companyDetails': {'id': data['companyDetails']['id'],
        'name': data['companyDetails']['name']}}
        ...
```

And so on. Desired output:

```
{'id': 123,
  'openingTimes': {'1': [{'opening': '12:00', 'closing': '16:00'},
    {'opening': '19:00', 'closing': '22:00'}],
   '2': [{'opening': '12:00', 'closing': '15:00'},
    {'opening': '19:00', 'closing': '22:00'}],
   '3': [{'opening': '12:00', 'closing': '15:00'},
    {'opening': '19:00', 'closing': '22:00'}],
   '4': [{'opening': '12:00', 'closing': '15:00'},
    {'opening': '19:00', 'closing': '23:00'}],
   '5': [{'opening': '12:00', 'closing': '15:00'},
    {'opening': '19:00', 'closing': '23:00'}],
   '6': [{'opening': '12:00', 'closing': '15:00'},
    {'opening': '19:00', 'closing': '00:00'}],
   '7': [{'opening': '12:00', 'closing': '16:00'},
    {'opening': '19:00', 'closing': '00:00'}]},
  'phoneNumber': '+44000',
  'companyDetails': {'id': 123456789,
   'name': 'ABCD'}}
```

I would like to inform everything inside `openingTimes` with the format data['...'] but I haven't found the way. Can somebody please help?

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Do you want to put the values of the  'Opening time' key of json_data in to a dataframe? or you want some values in the dataframe to be converted to json file?

Comment: I want to put the values of Opening time in the json data with the "data" dataframe info, just like the fields id, companydetails...

Comment: Sorry - the requirement is not clear. I do not see any pandas dataframe named 'data' in your description/code.  Rather "data" is a variable you are storing the json information whereas "json_data" is being assigned with a dictionary of json like information ...

Comment: Yes, sorry, what I want is to inform with the variable data the information that is inside openingtimes, like I do with ID or companydetails. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Do you mean you want to pull  all the values contained in 'json_data' variable/dictionary under ''openingTimes'' key ('Opening' & 'Closing'  times fo rthe IDs 1, 2 etc) in a tabular format using pandas data frame? you may post a desired sample output you want.

Answer (score 0):

Found the way!

```
'openingTimes': {'1': [{'opening': data['openingTimes']['1'][0]['opening'], 'closing': data['openingTimes']['1'][0]['closing']},
                               {'opening': data['openingTimes']['1'][1]['opening'], 'closing': data['openingTimes']['1'][1]['closing']}],
                         '2': [{'opening': data['openingTimes']['2'][0]['opening'], 'closing': data['openingTimes']['2'][0]['closing']},
                               {'opening': data['openingTimes']['2'][1]['opening'], 'closing': data['openingTimes']['2'][1]['closing']}],
                         '3': [{'opening': data['openingTimes']['3'][0]['opening'], 'closing': data['openingTimes']['3'][0]['closing']},
                               {'opening': data['openingTimes']['3'][1]['opening'], 'closing': data['openingTimes']['3'][1]['closing']}],
                         '4': [{'opening': data['openingTimes']['4'][0]['opening'], 'closing': data['openingTimes']['4'][0]['closing']},
                               {'opening': data['openingTimes']['4'][1]['opening'], 'closing': data['openingTimes']['4'][1]['closing']}],
                         '5': [{'opening': data['openingTimes']['5'][0]['opening'], 'closing': data['openingTimes']['5'][0]['closing']},
                               {'opening': data['openingTimes']['5'][1]['opening'], 'closing': data['openingTimes']['5'][1]['closing']}],
                         '6': [{'opening': data['openingTimes']['6'][0]['opening'], 'closing': data['openingTimes']['6'][0]['closing']},
                               {'opening': data['openingTimes']['6'][1]['opening'], 'closing': data['openingTimes']['6'][1]['closing']}],
                         '7': [{'opening': data['openingTimes']['7'][0]['opening'], 'closing': data['openingTimes']['7'][0]['closing']},
                               {'opening': data['openingTimes']['7'][1]['opening'], 'closing': data['openingTimes']['7'][1]['closing']}]},...
```

Thanks!